# How to add event listener for activities AnyChart 8

Tags: javascript, frontend, anychart

help please.
I try  add event listener on activities, but it is does not work. 
When I click on activity, I want to get IDs and continue to perform certain actions
**I use anychart v8**

I looked for information in the documentation but did not find an example
https://api.anychart.com/anychart.charts.Resource#listen

I tried so, the code is below. But that does not work. This is suitable for version 7, as I understand it

```
  this.data =data;
  let chart = anychart.resource(this.data);
  console.log(this.data);

  chart
    .zoomLevel(0)
    .timeTrackingMode('activity-per-resource')


  chart.calendar().availabilities([
    {
      each: 'day',
      from: 8,
      to: 18,
      isWorking: true
    }
  ]);


   var activities = chart.activities();
   chart.activities.listen("pointClick", function(e){
    console.log(e.data)
   });
  chart.draw();
  this.spinner.hide();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should listen to the event type from the chart, like this:

```
      chart.listen('pointClick', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
      });
```